# Show that $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ has an ideal $\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ and determine the elements of $(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z) / (\Bbb Z \times \{0\})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, ideals

> Show that $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ has an ideal $\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ and determine the elements of $(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z) / (\Bbb Z \times \{0\})$.

First off the group $(\Bbb Z \times \{0\}, +)$ is a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z, +)$ since for $a,b \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ we have that $a+b = (x,0)+(y,0) =(x+y,0) \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\}.$ Also the identity of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is in $\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ as $(0,0) \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$. For every $a \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ we have that $-a \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ for which $a+(-a)=(0,0).$

For $a \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ and $b \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ the products $$ab =(x,y)(z,0)=(xz,0) \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\} \\ ba =(z,0)(x,y)=(zx,0) \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\}$$ which makes $\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ an ideal of $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$.

Now the elements of $(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z) / (\Bbb Z \times \{0\})$ are of form $a+\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ for $a \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. And $$a+\Bbb Z \times \{0\}=\{(x,y)+(z,0) \mid (z,0) \in \Bbb Z \times \{0\} \}$$ but $$(x,y)+(z,0) =(x+z,y)$$ so the elements of $(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z) / (\Bbb Z \times \{0\})$ just the elements $(x,y) \in \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$?

Comment: The elements of a quotient ring are not elements of the "numerator" ring, but _equivalence classes_ of such elements. You're probably supposed to find a way to describe those equivalence classes such that each class is generated exactly once.

Comment: So many $\mathbb Z$ ! We could call it the Zorro ideal...

Comment: Maybe take a look at the isomorphism theorems for rings. Then construct a map such that the kernel is exactly $\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\}$.

Comment: A geometric perspective: the elements of the quotient are cosets of the integer lattice by the horizontal "line" $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$. What are these cosets?

Comment: @William It seem to be the integers lying on the $x$-axis?

Comment: In this case, $\mathbb{Z} \times \{0\}$ itself is the **identity element** of the quotient. So what would the elements of the quotient look like?

Comment: $(\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z) / (\Bbb Z \times \{0\})$ means that $\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ is the kernel of the quotient transformation so that whole subspace is the preimage of zero. The ring with elements of the form $\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ Now that you're quotienting it out you should get something left off, but not everything since the kernel is non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof proving that it is an ideal of  $R:= \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ is right. But, it's not right to say that the quotient ring is actually $ \Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$. What has happened is the notion of equality in the ring has changed, with an equivalence class, $a+I$ ($I :=\Bbb Z \times \{0\}$), of elements replacing multiple elements, $a+r$, $r\in I$, in the original ring $\Bbb Z \times \Bbb Z$ .

Comment: I am confused. By definition the elements of the quotient ring $R/I$ are $a + I$, where $a \in R$. Now in my case I have $a = (x,y)$ for $x,y \in \Bbb Z$. So $$a+I = (x,y) + \{(z,0) \mid z \in \Bbb Z\} = \{(x+z,y) \mid z \in \Bbb Z\}?$$

Comment: Yes. But this set, $a+I$ you are mentioning, is an element, not a subset, of the quotient ring. The quotient is a set of all such sets.

Comment: @Rico Jello Are you comfortable with the notion of an equivalence relation?

Answer (score 0):

Two elements $(a,b)$ and $(c,de)$ belong to the same equivalence class if $(c,d)=(a,b)+(z,0)$ for some $z$.
Thus $c=a+z$ and $d=b$ and hence each equivalence class is of the form
$(0,y) + \Bbb Z \times\{0\}$.